# Add Estimated delivery date range?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I want to add an estimated delivery date range. For example, if ordered today (21st Feb)

The required output should be something this:

**Estimated delivery by 24 Feb, Thursday to 26 Feb, Saturday**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'delivery_date_range',11 );
    
function delivery_date_range() {
   date_default_timezone_set( 'India' );  
    
 // date_from must be from 3rd day (from order date)
 // date_to must be the next 5th days
   
  $html = "<br><div>Estimated delivery by {$date_from} to {$date_to}</div>";
    
   echo $html;
}
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Do weekends matter? That generally extends delivery dates in most areas.

Comment: @Bazdin Generally we can skip Sunday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'delivery_date_range', 11);

function delivery_date_range() {

    // date_from must be from 3rd day (from order date)
    // date_to must be the next 5th days
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $three_day_from_today = date('j F, Y', strtotime($date . ' + 3 days'));
    $fifth_day_from_today = date('j F, Y', strtotime($date . ' + 5 days'));

    $html = "<br><div>Estimated delivery by {$three_day_from_today} to {$fifth_day_from_today}</div>";

    echo $html;
}
```

Check the manual for [PHP date format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: Output Coming as Estimated delivery by 2022-02-24 to 2022-02-26

But I needed like:  Estimated delivery by 24 Feb, Thursday to 26 Feb, Saturday

Comment: Thanks @mujuonly I figured out the solution , Thanks for the Answers, this exactly what I needed.